# Weird Scala test behavior with global variables: including a delay makes it succeed

Tags: scala, rest, testing, spray, akka-persistence

First, the whole code is in https://github.com/JJ/spray-test
I'm using a global object (which I don't know if it is Scala proper behavior) to share state in a Spray app. `put` adds to a Map, `get` obtains values from a map, thus:

```
path( Segment ) { quien =>
    get {
      println( Apuestas) // also Thread.wait(100)
      val esta_apuesta = Apuestas.get( quien )
      complete( esta_apuesta )
    } 
  }
```

(please check the whole file at https://github.com/JJ/spray-test/blob/master/src/main/scala/info/CC_MII/MyService.scala)

The essential parts of the test code is

```
 "Crea apuestas correctamente" in {
      Put( "/0/2/Alguien") ~> myRoute ~> check {
    response.entity should not be equalTo(None)
    responseAs[String] must contain("Alguien")
      }

       Put( "/3/0/Menda") ~> myRoute ~> check {
    response.entity should not be equalTo(None)
    responseAs[String] must contain("Menda")
      }
    }

    "GET recupera apuesta correctamente" in {
      Get("/Alguien") ~> myRoute ~> check {
    response.entity should not be equalTo(None)
    responseAs[String] must contain("Alguien")
      }
    }
```

The problem is in the first chunk of code. If I comment out the `println` statement it does not work and it fails.  This is the error message:
`[error]    'There was an internal server error.' doesn't contain 'Alguien' (MyServiceSpec.scala:49)`
Which obviously indicates that the "get" part hasn't worked yet, or it is in another thread, or I really don't have an idea of what's the matter.

It has probably something to do with synchronization and somesuch and I should probably have and declare Apuestas in some other way, but I'm quite new at this and I very happily would be enlightened.

I have also included this as an issue in the repo with the `hacktoberbest` label, just in case someone is interested in advancing one PR in that area. https://github.com/JJ/spray-test/issues

*Update*: This seems to be related to this question: [Unintended change to local variable of a Scala Actor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13463011/unintended-change-to-local-variable-of-a-scala-actor), that is, actors shouldn't share state but it's up to the program to enforce it. The thing is, well, they *do* share state but only if we print. Will maybe introducing a delay in the thread have the same effect? I know it's all bad form and worst practice and all the rest, but as said above, I'd happily be enlightened with the proper way of doing it.

*2nd update*: I have tried to synchronize methods thus:

```
  def add( apuesta: Apuesta ): Apuesta =  synchronized {
    {
      this.apuestas += ( apuesta.quien -> apuesta )
    }
    apuesta
  }
```

Still no dice. I still have either to print the whole Apuesta object or else to wait in the thread, which causes more problems. What does println do that can't be done via synchronization?

*Update 3*: After testing for a while, println only "synchronizes" part of the time. Still fails randomly. It's got to do with timing somehow, but can't see how.

Comment: This is not really a weird behaviour, it's just the way how concurrency looks to us human. There are some tools and models which are intended to mitigate difficulties with tracking flow of concurrent app, but they work only if you obey their constraints. Constraints like no shared state etc. Good point to start: https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/learning-concurrent-programming-scala

Comment: So, short of rewriting everything over, is anything that can be done about this?

Answer (score 2):

It's failing because you have a dependency between tests. `Put( "/0/2/Alguien")` has to be completed before you issue a `Get("/Alguien")` request. Otherwise, you have no entry with `alguien` key in the `info.CC_MII.Apuestas#apuestas`, and when you try to access it, your applications fails.

You introduced delay, in form of `print` or directly using `Thread.wait(100)`, and in this way gave time to `Put` request to complete. It would be just a bit better, if you would delay somehow test execution for `GET` instead of putting the print or sleep into the service.

The other option (better) could be making possible to inject state into `info.CC_MII.Apuestas`, the initial value for `apuestas` map. Then you could provide few entries during tests set up, and try to fetch them with `Get` request instead `Alguien`.

Comment: That does not quite seem to be the problem. First, on the test side, the calls are completed or the previous tests would have failed. There's no way, even, to sequence the calls other than program-wise. Second, on the server side, Thread.wait causes some problems: it simply drops calls if the test is done immediately after. Plus the funny thing about the println I mentioned is that it _needs_ to include the variable or it will not work. printing kicks some variable magic I'm not familiar with...Thread.wait doesn't work on test either.